# Why is my Euler Project code flawed?

Tags: c

I am attemping the euler project problem 2 to improve my programming and problem solving abilities. I am stuck at problem 2 however and I am not really sure what I'm going wrong in my code. Here is the problem:

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
>
> > 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

Here is my attempt at the solution.

```
#define MAX 4000000

int main()
{
    int num1=1, num2=1, temp, sum;

    while(num1<MAX || num2<MAX)
    {
        temp=num1+num2;
        num1=num2;
        num2=temp;
        if(temp%2==0)
            sum += temp;
    }
    printf("Sum= %d", sum);
}
```

The output I am getting (which is wrong) is

> Sum= 9212508

Comment: Please read this: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I forgot to include the macros when copy pasting the code. My apologies.

Comment: Also read this: http://devproconnections.com/development/c-sharp-code-writing-tips-eric-lippert-math The article is about C# but almost everything in it also applies to C. In particular read the section on integer arithmetic.

Comment: You're lucky you didn't get unicorns jumping all over your screen. That happened to me the last time I invoked undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yo didn't initialise `sum = 0`.
2. If `num1` is nearly at its limit, `sum` is necessarily larger.
3. `num1` < `num2`, so checking `num1` for size is a little pointless.
4. For debugging purposes, print `num1`, `num1`, and `sum` during every loop iteration.

Comment: #1 appears to be the issue. When I run his code, sum is being initialized with a value of 32,767